# how to convert bytes into ASCII in C language

Tags: microcontroller, uart, c

I am receiving bytes from my UART as uint8. How do I convert these bytes into ASCII? I am using Atmel 6.0 and my microcontroller is ATMega16L.

**EDIT**

I am using an android phone to send and receive information to a Wifi module (RN-131) from Roving networks. The wifi module connects to the microcontroller (atmega16L) through UART. Whatever the wifi module receives from the phone is transmitted out its UART. Similarly, whatever is written to its UART is transmitted out through wifi.

Now, what I'm trying to do is send a string from the phone which gets converted into bytes. The code is shown below:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new outputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
out.println("Eclipse");
```

here, the '**BufferedWriter**' - *Constructs a new BufferedWriter, providing out with a buffer of 8192 bytes.* and '**PrintWriter**' - *Constructs a new PrintWriter with out as its target writer. The parameter autoFlush determines if the print writer automatically flushes its contents to the target writer when a newline is encountered.*

now to program the microcontroller, I'm using AVR studio 6.0

```
uint8_t data;
char arr[32];
data = UDR;
length = strlen(data);
itoa(data, arr, 10);
```

But what I receive is "50, 53, 52" even when I'm sending "Eclipse".

**EDIT 20th June 2012**

Here is my code till now. Note: the code is written in AVR Studio 6.0 so it looks a bit different to other codes written in AVR Studio 4.18.

```
/**************************************************
 *  Includes
 */
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Atmel Studio 6.0/extensions/Atmel/AVRGCC/3.4.0.65/AVRToolchain/avr/include/avr/iom16.h"

/**************************************************
 *  Global Variables
 */
int trigger=0, length=0;
int i=0, n=0;
uint8_t data;
char arr[8];

/**************************************************
 *  Defines
 */
#define LED_PORT PORTA
#define RED_ON (PORTA | 0x01)
#define RED_OFF (PORTA & ~0x01)
#define YELLOW_ON (PORTA | 0x02)
#define YELLOW_OFF (PORTA & ~0x02)
#define GREEN_ON (PORTA | 0x04)
#define GREEN_OFF (PORTA & ~0x04)

/**************************************************
 *  Function Prototypes
 */
void initialize(void);                      
void time_display(void);

int main(void){
    initialize();

    while(1){
        //TODO:: Please write your application code

    }
}

void initialize(void){

    DDRA = 0x07; //PORTA pins 0,1,2 set as outputs
//  DDRD = 0x02; //PORTD pin 1 is output (TX) and pin 0 is input (RX)

    //Timer SETUP
    TCCR1A = 0x80; //OCR1A enable in CTC mode
    TCCR1B = 0x0C; //CTC mode, 256 prescale 
    TIMSK = 0x10; //CTC on OCR1A enabled, overflow disabled
    OCR1A = 2000; //OCR value set to get an interrupt every 1 second (15624)

    //USART SETUP
    UCSRA = 0x00; //no Frame Error, no parity error, no Data OverRun
    UCSRB = 0xE0; //receiver enable, transmitter enable (0x18)
    UCSRC = 0x8E; //Asynchronous USART mode, no parity, 1 stop bit, 8-bit character size, Data transmitted on rising edge and received on falling edge of the clock
    UBRRL = 51; //Baud rate of 9600bps
    UBRRH = 0;

    sei(); //Global interrupt enable
}

//timer capture interrupt
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){

}

ISR(USART_RXC_vect){
    LED_PORT = RED_ON;
    _delay_ms(100);

    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        arr[x] = UDR;
    }

    LED_PORT = RED_OFF;
    _delay_ms(100);

    trigger = 1;
}

ISR(USART_UDRE_vect){
    if(trigger >= 1){
        LED_PORT = GREEN_ON;
        _delay_ms(200);
        LED_PORT = GREEN_OFF;
        _delay_ms(200);

        UDR = data; //transmit the data
        trigger = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, uint8 is a 0 to 255 integer already, which by definition = char ... how much more ASCII could it be?

Comment: i know that too, but im receiving rubbish from my UART using uint8

Comment: Try casting each byte as a char.

Comment: @DavidNorman It sounds like something is getting lost in translation. You may have to scope out what's being received to decipher it.

Comment: yeah I might have to do that. I receive little diamonds from the microcontroller, never seen that before. Shown below is what im trying to do. 'data' is uint16_t datatype. 'tx' is char[32] datatype.
`data = (uint16_t) tx;
length = strlen(data);
UDR = data;`

Comment: Print your received data as hex or an integer, and look it up on an ASCII table. That usually produces some clues as to what is going on. The "little diamonds" could mean a lot of things, the most likely that whatever is displaying the characters simply does not know how to interpret them, and the diamond character is simply a place-holder.

Comment: what is a 'place-holder'?

Comment: @DavidNorman What device are you receiving UART data from?  Where is it going? (computer to uC? uC to computer? SOme other device to uC?)

Comment: Also, you are using strlen() on a 16 bit integer.  the strlen() function is expecting a string, so it is counting locations in memory into it finds the termination ascii character '\0'.  I think you are still confused on what your data is represented as still.  Can you maybe expand your main post and add more detail> (your code, set up, etc)

Comment: alrite ill do that

Comment: Why are you doing this? `length = strlen(data);` This could be pretty dangerous... What's happening there is that it's looking at the memory address "data" and trying to find a null-terminated string there.  Since we don't know what's there, it could count until it crashes.

Comment: i guess that is whats happening. I get different data each time i receive something. How do I fix it? I dont know any way around it.

Comment: @DavidNorman, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by calling `strlen` there. For one, if you wanted to get the length of the incoming string, that won't do it the way you have it.  `UDR` is where a single byte will reside, not your entire string.  Second of all, `strlen` needs a pointer to memory where your desired string is located to measure. You've passed it a value, not a pointer. This is going to get interpreted as a memory address and it will start counting in a location where who knows what will be there...

Comment: @Jon - thats exactly what I'm trying to do. I was thinking of looping the bytes I receive from the buffer and store it into an array. But I guess that is not possible now. I am trying to send a message from the phone to the wifi module to turn an LED on or off

Comment: @DavidNorman, edited my comment with a bit more info.  And it's totally possible to do what you you've described there (looping and storing in a buffer), but it looks like its not quite there yet...  I'll try to add more to my answer to help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3809/discussion-between-jon-l-and-david-norman)

Comment: You need to specify the encoding (called `CharSet` in Java) in `new OutputStringWriter(stream, charset)`, otherwise it uses some default that could be wrong. Though most likely it is UTF-8, which includes ASCII as a subset and would work.  So I doubt this is the root of your problem.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @starblue - I checked the format and its UTF8. so yeah you're right this is not the root of the problem. still trying to figure things out

Comment: Just one small advice *NEVER* use delays in a Interrupt Service Routine, you want your ISR to be as quick as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 6/19/2012***********************************************************

Ok, so after you added your code I have made a few changes for you to try (and to understand!)

First of all, we have declared our character array volatile so that the compiler knows it may change unexpectedly from an interrupt.  Likewise, we have created a variable to keep track of our index position in the array:

```
/**************************************************
 *  Global Variables
 */
int trigger=0, length=0;
int i=0, n=0;
uint8_t data;
volatile char arr[8];
volatile char arr_idx = 0;
```

Next, i have edited your UART initialization code based on the ATMega16L Datasheet and your comments:

```
//USART SETUP
UCSRA = 0x00; //no Frame Error, no parity error, no Data OverRun
UCSRB = 0xD8; //receiver enable, transmitter enable (0x18)
UCSRC = 0x86; //Asynchronous USART mode, no parity, 1 stop bit, 8-bit character size, Data transmitted on rising edge and received on falling edge of the clock
UBRRL = 51; //Baud rate of 9600bps (8MHz clock?)
UBRRH = 0;
```

Look closely at the [datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/ATMEGA16L-8PU-Atmel-datasheet-810.pdf) (page ~166).  I believe I have correctly configures the UART now based on your comments.  I will not go over each bit, but you should.  Please ask questions if you think I made a mistake or you don't get something.

Finally, I have edited your ISR routine:

```
ISR(USART_RXC_vect){
    arr[arr_idx] = UDR;
    arr_idx++;
    arr_idx %= 7; //make sure index stays within array

    trigger = 1;
}
```

Note that, the ISR is executed every time a single byte (or character) is received.  This means we want to process the single character (add it to our array), increment our index location, and get out of it quickly so that we are ready for the next character to come in.

You now need to look at the arr[] through whatever method you have been using and see if it is now receiving your characters correctly.

**END OF EDIT****************************************

One option is to just use one of the available libraries included in AVR Studio:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and then somewhere in your code...

```
char num2[5]; //create a buffer for the ascii string
itoa(num1,num2,10); //convert the integer (num1) to an ascii string (num2) in base 10
```

If you are then displaying this on a character LCD, you can send the num2 array to the lcd print function that you are using.

If you are concerned about code space you can fairly easily write your own simple itoa (integer to ascii) function. You will need to grab each "tens" position from your integer using the "/" and "%" operators and convert it to ascii:

[image]
<sub>(source: [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif))</sub>

From the table above, you can see that once you grab each digits value (0-9), just add 48 to it to convert it into the ascii character representation.

**EDIT**

Ok, so after you adding your information and assuming:

- You have correctly initialized the UART baud rate etc on your ATMEGA
- The android code is successfully sending the ascii bytes across the WiFly and out of its UART

Then the microcontroller should already be receive these characters as Ascii, and the ITOA  function is not what is needed here and in fact would mess up your string data coming in.

It could still be a lot of different things though...How are you viewing the uart data that is being received by your microcontroller?

Comment: well I look at the watch window for incoming characters, I have seen that when I send a string to the microcontroller's UART which is "Eclipse" what I receive is this: _{171, 70, 254, 70, 70, 70, 70}_ in my character array. What does this mean? I dont think this is the data I'm suppose to receive

Comment: @DavidNorman The problem is complicated enough that it is still guess work on what could be wrong.  If you are still having troubles after more attempts, you should post your actual C file code (whole code, not just snippets) so that we can properly debug it.  Once we know you are reading the UART correctly we can better isolate the problem.

Comment: you're right ill upload my code now

Comment: @DavidNorman, justin says something important here: `Note that, the ISR is executed every time a single byte (or character) is received`.  Every time that happens, `UDR` will have a new value.  You don't need to have the loop within the ISR.  Hopefully that will give you enough insight to solve the problem.

Comment: @JonL - this time I tried sending "123" but what I receive is just two bytes, which are 85 and 133. Every time I send "123" I get 85 and 133. Why is this happening?

Comment: @justin - thanks a lot buddy, I noticed I had a mistake in UCSRC, I had set for 2 stop bits by mistake instead of 1 stop bit. I am using a 4MHz crystal which was my 2nd mistake. I changed UBRRL to 25

Comment: @DavidNorman No problem. If you get your UART figured out be sure and mark an answer as correct.  be sure and go back and finish all of your other questions you have posted on this site as well, either by marking an answer as good or editing your question to get better feedback.  People will want to help you more if you acknowledge their time put in.

Comment: @justin - will do

Comment: I believe one thing that also solved your problem was removing delays from ISR...

Comment: @justin - i got my code working, the problem was the delays in the interrupt function, and the changes from your code above helped. so yeah, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

An ASCII character is simply an 8-bit number that is displayed as a character when you call functions like "printf" that are meant to display characters.

In C, a string is an array of these characters (or 8-bit numbers) that is terminated with the value `0` or "null-terminated".

So when you send a string like "Eclipse", you're actually sending numbers already.  In fact, this is what it looks like when you send it:

`[69, 99, 108, 105, 112, 115, 101, 0]`

Passing this to `printf`, for example, will print "Eclipse".  Note the null-terminator. Also note that you don't need any function to convert this.

`itoa` is a function used to convert numbers to their string representation.  For example:

```
 char str[32];
 itoa(223, str, 10);
 printf("%s", str);
```

This would print out "223".  The actual number values that reside in `str[]` that we know of for sure: `[50, 50, 51, 0]`.  From your description, I'm pretty sure that this is not what you want.

**Don't always assume ASCII** encoding. Here's an extremely widely-used character encoding in use at the application level and web development: [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) - These characters are not always 8-bits, some of them are 16-bits to represent characters in other languages for example.

**EDIT:**

There is something that you need to know about a typical UART peripheral on an AVR (not meant to be a blanket statement for all UART's on all uC's, just the family that you are using).  They work like this: when a byte comes in, it gets put into a single-byte memory location: `UDR` - When you do a read from this register, it will be cleared.  If new data is coming in on the UART and you haven't read from this register yet? It's going to get overwritten with the new value.  Entire strings will not be placed here.  Just single characters.  All of this is described in the datasheet for your uC, I highly recommend getting familiar with it.

Hopefully, that will give you enough information to understand why `strlen(data)` won't work. If you're still not sure why, read over the datasheet, read up on what happens when you make this assignment in C `data = UDR;` and also read what `strlen`'s parameters are, and note that one of them is a *pointer* to a string.  If you don't have a good grasp on pointers, I highly suggest this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

If this all sounds like too much work to you, then I suggest picking up an Arduino instead.  Don't get me wrong, it would be awesome if you could grasp all of this and be using plain C on your AVR, but if there are too many gaps in your knowledge at the moment, then it may be a bit overwhelming.

Now, on to what you want to accomplish.  You mentioned in your comment that you wanted to loop until you get a full string out of the UART, storing it into a buffer, where you will then process it as a command. Ok. Totally do-able, in fact, a somewhat common technique.

Here's some psuedo code for you:

```
i = 0;
char str[32];

while(forever) {
   if (data_byte_is_available) {
        if (i == 31)
             i = 0;
        str[i] = UDR;
        i++;
   }
   print(str);
}
```

Try to figure out what you need to do for a `data_byte_is_available` function.  The datasheet is your friend.  Also, how are you displaying what is coming in on the uC's UART?  Whatever that is, substitute the `print` I have up there with that.  I hope there's no issues with whatever you're using there...

Comment: @DavidNorman, if you'd like to add some more information, please edit your original post.  I see you were trying to show me an ISR - great.  You can post it in your original question.

Comment: ASCII is only 7-bit. The character sets used by modern computers tend to be based on ASCII, such as ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1). More details at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII